# State Transition Diagrams for XOR

Tags: finite-automata, boolean-algebra

I have found two different versions for State Transition Diagrams for XOR.

I'm confused as to why one has 2 states and the other has 3. What are the implied states in each please?

Are they both functionally equivalent? Are there situations where one is more appropriate than the other?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "State Transition Diagram for XOR"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left you have a DFA that accepts the language of all strings over $\{0,1\}$ in which the XOR equals 1.

On the right you have a Mealy machine in which each output is the XOR of the two recent inputs (the first output is always zero).